# Join 3 tables; select a list from specific group

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables

**Table#1**: groups

```
|---------------|---------------|
|  id_group     |    Name       |
|-------------------------------|
|    1          |    Group 1    |
--------------------------------|
|    2          |    Group 2    |
--------------------------------|
|    3          |    Group 3    |
--------------------------------|
```

**Table#2**: jobs

```
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|
|     id_job    |    id_group   |      name_job        |
|---------------|--------------------------------------|
|      1        |    1          |       name_1         |
-------------------------------------------------------|
|      2        |    1          |       name_2         |
-------------------------------------------------------|
|      3        |    2          |       name_3         |
-------------------------------------------------------|
|      4        |    3          |       name_4         |
-------------------------------------------------------|
|      5        |    3          |       name_5         |
-------------------------------------------------------|
|      6        |    3          |       name_6         |
-------------------------------------------------------|
```

**Table#3**: users

```
|---------------|---------------|
|  user         |    id_job     |
|-------------------------------|
|    A          |       1       |
--------------------------------|
|    B          |       1       |
--------------------------------|
|    C          |       4       |
--------------------------------|
|    D          |       6       |
--------------------------------|
```

If I were an user (e.g C), the result I'd look for is a page where there is a table with 2 columns (USERS | JOB).

The column USERS should be filled in with all the users who share the same group. The column JOB should be filled in with all name_job of the specific group group as follows:

```
         LOGIN: C
|---------------|---------------|
|  user         |       job     |
|-------------------------------|
|    C          |       name_4, |
|               |       name_5, |
|               |       name_6  |
--------------------------------|
|    D          |       name_4, |
|               |       name_5, |
|               |       name_6  |
--------------------------------|
```

I tried with this code, but the result is that I can read people who share the same group with me, but I can't read the jobs.

```
SELECT users.* jobs.* 
FROM users JOIN jobs ON users.id_job=jobs.id_job 
WHERE job.id_group IN 
(SELECT job.id_group 
FROM users JOIN jobs ON users.id_job = jobs.id_job 
WHERE users.user= '$login')
```

Your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want the list all jobs of the group the user belongs to. One option uses a correlated subquery and string aggregation:

```
select u.*,
    (
        select group_concat(j1.name_job order by j1.id_job)
        from jobs j
        inner join jobs j1 on j1.id_group = j.id_group
        where j.id_job = u.id_job
    ) as job_names
from users u
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to study your code, but there're some elements I don't understand. What's the difference between j and j1? Why there's a u in the last line (from users I)? Can you help me out? Thank you in advance :)